# Postgres SQL Query that returns JSON object with keys from one column and values from another column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I want to create a (Postgres) SQL Query that returns a JSON object. The keys should be the entries from one column (eg. ID) and the values the entries from another column (eg. name).
My table looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foods (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR(100)
);
INSERT INTO foods(name)
VALUES  ('Apple'),
        ('Banana'),
        ('Lemon');
```

Running example:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=96c8ee3de02647333752a30b9cfc8674

The result should look like this:

```sql
{
  "1": "Apple",
  "2": "Banana",
  "3": "Lemon"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `json[b]_object_agg()`:

```
select jsonb_object_agg(id, name) res
from foods
```